# How can I hide a Trac project from the project listing?

Tags: trac, genshi

Right now I'm using Trac with multiple projects and have customized the project-listing template a bit, but currently there are about 5 Trac projects, and I only want 4 of them to be showing. I successfully hid the last one by adding a py:if conditional against the exact name of the project, but that seems like a terrible way of doing it.

Is there a flag or anything I could set in each project's trac.ini that would make it not show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring the code modification you stated, I think the only way you would be able to do this is to use TRAC_ENV_PARENT_DIR in your httpd config to group the 4 common projects, and then move the 5th to another location on the filesystem.

This will require a lot of fabulous Apache Config hacks to get the 5th project to work properly, and honestly you've already taken the path with the quickest solution.